# How to properly setup a single log file repository system

Tags: logs

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can setup a single-system repository so that multiple OS servers  can report send there logs to that single-repository solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use rsyslogd with the [relp protocol](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/relp.html).

At the server, put into /etc/rsyslog.conf this:

```
$ModLoad imrelp
$InputRELPServerRun 2514
```

And at the client side:

```
$ModLoad omrelp
...
*.* :omrelp:server.address:2514
```

You have to install relp plugin:

```
apt-get install rsyslog-relp
```

It is better to put server.address to /etc/hosts, so that you do not have to rely on working DNS.